# Accelerometer data handling is slowing down output

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, accelerometer, data-processing

I'm attempting to write 3 axis accelerometer data to a file but I need the data to be sampled at a specific frequency (Ideally Min of 4 to 6 KHz (Max Sensor rating)). Running into an issue where reading/printing/appending the accelerometer data is slowing down  the loop frequency to 2 kHz and less, re-running the program continues to drop the frequency as well. Currently I have it running in a while loop with a counter and writing out to a file when it reaches 6664 samples. Reducing the handling to a single axis increases the sampling frequency from ~2.2k to 2.9k.

I think my issue is how the data is being handled in the while loop, is there a faster way to process this without editing the driver/library? <s>Is there a way to reduce the amount of digits the tuple is presenting on my end? I attempted to try to round but it doesn't work the way I assumed for tuples.</s>

One  last resort solution would be to clone the driver and get the raw accelerometer data in bytes/bits? then convert later.

**3 Axis sample**

```py
try:
    f.write(current_time + "\n\n")
    start = timer()
    buff = list()
    while(True):
        count += 1
        buff.append(sensor.acceleration)
        if (len(buff) == 6664):
            end = timer()
            for i, value in enumerate(buff):
                f.write("%f %f %f \n" % value)
            elapsed = round((end-start),5)
            print("Samples: " + str(count))
            print("Elapsed time: " + str(elapsed))
            print("Frequency: " + str(round(count/elapsed,5)))
            f.close()
            sys.exit()
```

**Terminal Output**

```
Samples: 6664
Elapsed time: 2.93079
Frequency: 2273.78966

Samples: 6664
Elapsed time: 2.90476
Frequency: 2294.16544

Samples: 6664
Elapsed time: 2.96278
Frequency: 2249.23889
```

**.txt File output**

```
02:26:59

0.571885 0.193819 9.999606 
0.641276 0.157926 10.045069 
0.488136 0.088534 9.973285 

...
```

Driver:
[https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_LSM6DS][1]

Comment: so, ``sensor.acceleration``, yields 3 floats? If so, do you know precision?

Comment: Ah, now that you mention it. It looks like it is a float (new to python and didn't really understand what a tuple was thought it was just a type). But I was able to directly append the float to 2 decimal points and the speed seems to be the same.

Comment: ok, what happens if you run the code I posted below?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't proofed this but:

1. Use `numpy`. Python lists are great for appending, but not so much for iterations.

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

try:
    f.write(current_time + "\n\n")
    buff = np.zeros(shape=(6665, 3), dtype=np.float)
    start = timer()
    # buff = list()
    # while(True):
    while count < 6665:
        buff[count][:] = sensor.acceleration
        count += 1
        # buff.append(sensor.acceleration)
        # if (len(buff) == 6664):
    end = timer()
    for i, value in enumerate(buff):
        f.write("%f %f %f \n" % value)

    elapsed = round((end-start),5)
        
    print("Samples: " + str(count))
    print("Elapsed time: " + str(elapsed)
    print("Frequency: " + str(round(count/elapsed,5)))
    f.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Error Output:

    f.write("%f %f %f \n" % value)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: ``f.write("%f %f %f \n" % (value[0], value[1], value[2]))``

Comment: Result seems to fluctuate from 1900 - 2200. Elapsed time AVG: 3.0 - 3.5 seconds. I'm starting to think it might be how the data type is processed by the helper taking too much time?